# IIS Rewrite with n number of query string

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to write IIS rewrite rule in config file. I am able to write simple redirection rule in config with known query string in URL.

for example

```
<rule name="qs-redirect">
    <match url="^services\/?$" />  
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^.*\.?uat.abc\.com$" />
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="insurance-video" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://uat.abc.com/services/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
  </rule>
```

Now the situation is , if user type

"**www.abc.com/Video**" then it should redirect to  to: **www.abc.com/doctor/?doctorvideo=true** 
but if URL is

"**www.abc.com/Video?qs1=1&qs2=2...&qsN=n**"

then it must maintain **"?doctorvideo=true"** query string in Destination URLs and append the all QS in last as below

"**www.abc.com/doctor/?doctorvideo=true&qs1=1&qs2=2...&qsN=n**"

Comment: Just redirect `^Video$` to `www.abc.com/doctor/?doctorvideo=true` and set `appendQueryString="true"`. No `{QUERY_STRING}` condition required.

Comment: Thanks it works as you suggested